# Is that possible to check an iPad's total power-on lifetime since its manufacture?

Tags: ipad

I just bought a brand new 2019 iPad Air. But I am afraid it's not a brand new one. I know I could check the model or serial number, but I don't really trust that approach.

I think it's best to check the power-on lifetime if there is a hidden feature in Settings somewhere (or enter some magic numbers in the dial-up panel like what Android devices do).

Thus is it possible to check iPad's total power-on lifetime since its manufacture?

Comment: Why don't you trust checking the serial number with Apple?  They're the authority on when a device was sold because it determines when the warranty starts.

Comment: @fsb what if the ipad is a sample device and never activated, registered? All it did are powering on and showing the "Hello" screen to buyers?

Comment: @sgon00 Those devices, so called "demo devices" which are used in store are also refurbished and sold by Apple. The way device serial numbers are encoded, it's straightforward to determine if the device was a demo device, refurbished or a brand new one. Go through this page: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Comment: @NimeshNeema the thing is I don't trust the people in my country will follow any rules...

Comment: @sgon00 In that case you can for sure trust the Limited Warranty item as described in the answer. That in addition to the cycle count should give you good enough confidence. Also, there’s no away a middle man can forge the serial number. (Or probably you should reconsider where you make the purchases from).

Comment: @NimeshNeema thanks for the answer. Yeah, serial number and battery cycle count will give a very good measurement. Btw the pity thing is I don't trust any stores in my Country, and It will take too much work to buy one from another country. :)

Comment: The serial number can be checked at [Apple's Warranty page](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/).  The stores in your country can't change the dates that Apple has indicated for warranty coverage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not generally possible to determine the total power-on lifetime of an iOS device.

To determine how much the device is used, a better indicator is to determine the battery charge cycle count. A single charge cycle count is equivalent to one complete discharge or the device's battery. For a new device, the cycle count value is a low value between 0-2.

To determine the battery charge cycle count, you can use an app such as [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/).

[image]

Additionally, if you are running the current latest version of iOS 12, you can determine is still covered under limited warranty. On your iPad, go to Settings app → About and look for an item named Limited Warranty. It will show the warranty expiry data. The devices whose warranty has expired, this item is not shown altogether.

[image]

The last mentioned approach uses the device serial number and fetches the warranty expiry date from Apple's servers. Since the limited warranty for iOS devices bought from Apple is for 1 year from the date of purchase, I think it's a good measure that can be used to determine the genuinity of the device.

These two approaches should help you with confidently getting answer for your concerns.

Comment: Hi, sorry to interrupt. A quick question how to install coconutBattery in ipad? I did search coconutBattery on AppStore, but no such app. The website does not provide a detail installation instruction for ipad either. Thanks.

Comment: @sgon00 coconutBattery is a macOS app. You'll need a Mac to run coconutBattery. They don't have an iOS app yet.

Comment: Is there any other way to check the cycle count inside the ipad without a MacOS or PC? In the current situation, there is no MacOS and PC around. (My friend is trying to do this and I am not at the same city).

Comment: @sgon00 It is not possible to determine cycle count "on device". No 3rd party app can do that. You'll need access to a desktop computer for that (either macOS or Windows will do). A similar stat in the form of battery health percentage is shown on devices running iOS 11.3 and later (except iPhone 5s).

Answer (score 1):

I know that it’s been a while but I believe I’ve found a way, and would like to leave it here for other people to see.

1. Go to **Settings** > **Privacy & Security** > **Analytics & Improvements** > **Analytics Data**
2. Go to the latest analytic file (second from the top)
3. Scroll all the way down and look for `last_value_TotalOperatingTime`.  There should be a number next to it that shows the total power on time. It could take a while to find but you should be able to do it.

You can also find the battery capacity this way.

To do this, you must have share analytics with Apple turned on.